# Copying data in azure synapse analytics workspace failed on folder destination

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

got the following weird error while using the wizard to load data into azure synapse workspace data lake storage gen2:

ADLS Gen2 operation failed for: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'. Account: 'datalakestorage1'. FileSystem: 'filesystem'. ErrorCode: 'AuthorizationPermissionMismatch'. Message: 'This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.'. . Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
This may happen if your data source only allows secured connections. If that's the case, please create a new workspace with virtual network option enabled.

source is snowflake data